# Что за кодировка, и как это декодить на php?

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка, php

\x447\x435\x440\x43d\x438\x433\x43e\x432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это строка записанная в utf-8. Закодированное слово - "чернигов".

**как это закодированно:** \x - значит, что дальше будет число, записанное в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления. Так как там по три знака, то это два байта. То есть, `04 47 04 35 04 40 04 3d 04 38 04 33 04 3e 04 32`.

как декодировать в php  по красивому - не знаю. Но придумал такое - вначале заменить \x на знак процента и применить urlencode.

[здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320516/how-to-convert-text-to-x-codes) показано, как так закодировать.

Comment: Нашел решение:
html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~\\\x([a-f0-9]+)~i','&#x$1;',$string),0,'UTF-8')

благодарю за подсказку!

подробнее:
1) превращаем это в html-последовательности: \xКОД -> &#xКОД;
2) декодим строку html_entity_decode

Answer (score 0):

Накодировано мама не горюй...

> \x447\x435\x440\x43d\x438\x433\x43e\x432

ASCII кодировка, поборимся средствами JS чтобы понять в чем дело)

```
alert('\x447\x435\x440\x43d\x438\x433\x43e\x432');//Результат - D7C5D0CdC8C3CeC2
```

Идем дальше, подставим к результату ту же архитектуру ASCII

```
alert('\xD7\xC5\xD0\xCd\xC8\xC3\xCe\xC2');//Результат - ×ÅÐÍÈÃÎÂ
```

`О_о`

Идем к А. Лебедеву и пользуемся [тулзой](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/advanced/) и превращаем **×ÅÐÍÈÃÎÂ** в результате в **ЧЕРНИГОВ**

З.Ы. Мне вот инетересно, зачем так извращаться на простыми словами?..

Comment: эт скорее всего взято с какогото сайта, на котором названия городов (?) хранятся в таком виде... встречал не раз, так что это не тс развлекается ;) и вопрос актуален, как это налету декодировать на php

Comment: @thunder я и не говорю что ТС развлекался) И о неактуальности вопроса не упоминал!